# Find max value comparing multiple arrays for each index

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to find a method to find the max value comparing multiple(unknown number, but same length) arrays for each observation in the arrays, returning an array with the max values.

Example:

**EDIT**:

```
 A = [[2.2, 3.3, 1.3], [1.2, 5.3, 2.2], [0.3, 2.2, 5.2], etc......]
```

Returning

```
MAX = [2.2, 5.3, 5.2]
```

Able to check that the 'input'-arrays are of the same length, but not able to compare the arrays finding the max....?

Comment: don't you mean `MAX = [3.3,5.3,5.2]`?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: No, I would like to compare A[0] with B[0] with C[0].. and A[1] with B[1] with C[1] etc.. Not to find the max value in each array, but across the arrays for 0:length-1...

Comment: You should make an array of arrays forwarded to function finding largest numbers.

Comment: @DiKey: Kind of what i'm not able to do.. Are you able to give an example?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
    var A = [[2.2, 3.3, 1.3], [1.2, 5.3, 2.2], [0.3, 2.2, 5.2]];
    
    var max = A.reduce(function(final, current) {
      for (var i = 0; i < final.length; ++i) {
        if (current[i] > final[i]) {
          final[i] = current[i];
        }
      }
      return final;
    });
    
    console.log(max);
```

The inner function compares the current maximum with the next array element and so `final` always holds the maximum value for all elements traversed thus far.

Answer (score 2):

For each index of the array, create an array containing all elements in the "column" and find the max of those values. Return the generated array. Sample usage: `maxValues(A)` would give the desired result.

```
function maxValues(array) {
    var maxArray = [];
    var length = array[0].length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var ithColumn = [].map.call(array, function(array) {
            return array[i];
        });
        maxArray.push(Math.max.apply(null, ithColumn));
    }
    return maxArray;
}
```

Comment: thanks openorclose! please someone upvote for correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = [
    [2.2, 3.3, 1.3],
    [1.2, 5.3, 2.2],
    [0.3, 2.2, 5.2]
];

function maxAtIndex (data) {
    //output
    var maxArray = [];
    //loop arrays passed in
    for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        var possibleValues = [];
        //get value in array at index
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            possibleValues.push(data[j][i]);
        }
        //get the highest from possible values
        var highest = Math.max.apply(null, possibleValues);
        //store in output array
        maxArray.push(highest);
    }
    return maxArray;
};

console.log(maxAtIndex(data)); //[ 2.2, 5.3, 5.2 ]
```

Comment: thanks jmfolds! please someone upvote for correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short and sweet version:

```
var A = [[2.2, 3.3, 1.3], [1.2, 5.3, 2.2], [0.3, 2.2, 5.2]];

var maxA = A.map(a => Math.max.apply(null, a));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine Lo-Dash's [zip](https://lodash.com/docs#zip) and [map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) methods to do this in just a few lines of code:

```
var A = [[2.2, 3.3, 1.3], [1.2, 5.3, 2.2], [0.3, 2.2, 5.2]];

// Creates an array of arrays, where the first array is all the first elements,
// the second array is all the second elements, etc.
var zipped = _.zip(A);
var maxes = _.map(zipped, function(arr) {
    return _.max(arr);
});
console.log(maxes);
```

Comment: There's a typo in your answer: because lodash's interface for _.zip changed, you'll have to apply it with `_.zip.apply(null, A)`.

Answer (score 0):

I took [Tom Panning's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117741/1757964) and simplified it even further:

```
var A = [[2.2, 3.3, 1.3], [1.2, 5.3, 2.2], [0.3, 2.2, 5.2]];
var MAX = _.zip.apply(null, A).map(_.max);
```