# Return Largest Numbers in Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to find the largest numbers in a group of arrays and return them into new array. But i dont get why my code is not working. Can you explain me my mistakes?

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      arr[i].sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a;
      });

    }
  }
}

largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);
```

Comment: "Not working" means what? Do you get errors? Is your output not what you'd expect?

Comment: You are sorting `arr[i]` inside the loop over `j`, what sense is that supposed to make? That's just gonna perform the same sort operation several times.

Comment: *not working* is an absolutely meaningless problem description. If you want help here, be **specific**. How is it intended to work, and how **specifically** is it not working the way it is meant to be?

Comment: And what is the actual result you want? Be precise, don't leave it open to possible interpretation. I am assuming you want `[5, 27, 39, 1001]` as a result? Then you want _one_ loop over the outer array, inside that you sort the current inner array, and then pick the maximum value from that (either first or last, depending on sort order), and put it into your new array.

Comment: Sorry for miss information. I am sure that my code has alot of problems. I thougth it'd work but it didnt.(No output)  I can use premade solutions to pass that lesson. I just wanted to know whats wrong with this one. And yes, I want biggest number from each array as a result.

Comment: If you look for the largest number of each array then take a look at the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37139885/1960455)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find max value comparing multiple arrays for each index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116862/find-max-value-comparing-multiple-arrays-for-each-index)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the largest *n* values from all arrays, you could flatten the list, sort, and voila.

```
var arrayOfArrys = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];
var flattened = [];

for (var _i = 0, arrayOfArrys_1 = arrayOfArrys; _i < arrayOfArrys_1.length; _i++) {
    var arr = arrayOfArrys_1[_i];
    flattened = flattened.concat(arr);
}

var sorted = flattened.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the array with the largest SUM (because you said you want the biggest "numbers" not "number"), you could do something like:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var sums = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      var arraySum = 0;
      for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        arraySum+=arr[i][j];
      }
      sums.push({array: arr[i], sum: arraySum});
   }
   return sums.sort(function(a,b){return b.sum - a.sum})[0].array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A first pass refactoring that gets the basic functionality in place involve using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the maximal value:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      arr[i].sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a;
      });

    }
  }

  // Extract the first element from each array.
  return arr.map(function(a) { return a[0] });
}
```

A second pass involves just using `map` more aggressively as well as using `max` instead of `sort`:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(a) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, a);
  });
}
```

This side-steps the ugly `sort(function(a,b) { ... })` junk required to do a numerical sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has got a lot of problems.

- You're sorting the inner arrays while you're looping through them, meaning for an array of size `n` you're sorting that array `n` times. This needlessly inefficient.
- Sorting at all is inefficient if you just want the max / min element; sorting in general is a **O(n log n)** operation, but just looping through the array is **O(n)** (see [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for more information).
- Although your code is sorting the inner arrays, you're not doing anything with the result (i.e. the first elements of the sorted inner arrays).
- You are not returning anything from your function or modifying the input array to contain the result (if the intent was to modify the array 'in-place' as the return value).

To resolve these problems:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var result = [], max, jMax;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    max = arr[i][0];
    for (var j = 1; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (max < arr[i][j])
        max = arr[i][j];
    }
    result.push(max);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(
  largestOfFour([
    [4, 5, 1, 3],
    [13, 27, 18, 26],
    [32, 35, 37, 39],
    [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
  ])
);
```

Or more cleanly, use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(x) {
    return x.reduce(function(a, c) {
      return c < a ? a : c;
    });
  });
}


console.log(largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]));
```